# Adding a class to the last row of a table (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am pretty new to CodeIgniter (and php, even to html and this world actually...) and I am trying to add a class to the last row of a table. Well, actually I'd like to use the `<th>` tag instead of `<td>` for the cells in that last row. Just managing to add a class would work fine for me.

I have tried to search in the manual and some forums, no success.

I am using the library table.

I have the feeling that it has to be done via the `set_template($tmpl)` method but I don't know how flexible it is; as long as I can see, it only allows you to give a value to a certain amount of predefined variables and that's all.

Comment: hint, don't use a TH (Table header) anywhere but in the first column. Think semantics, if you where trying to read the source code outputted by your script and saw table headers at the bottom of the table, would you freak out?

Comment: is this to build a table of results - but the number of results will change? otherwise you can just add a class to the row and then add CSS to make that row bold etc like a TH .

Comment: You can either use css or jquery to target the last tr element and add it. Your questions is too vague. You can use this query to set it, `$("table tr:last-child th").addClass("whateverClassYouWantToAdd");`.

Comment: OP is attempting to use http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html table class to add a class to the final row of his table. No, the class doesn't have this, unless you want to add rows one at a time. Use ISuthan Bala's suggestion

Comment: I managed to add the CSS I wanted to the cells of the last row of the table, thanks for your responses.